# How to add marker to simple Google maps link location?

Tags: php, google-maps

I would like to have a plain link to Google map location by latitude and longitude (For example, I have "45.799793,15.970302").

```
https://www.google.com/maps/@45.799793,15.970302,10z
```

This link works but how can I append a marker on same location? When user goes to that link he should see the marker location just like in this link which is a mess to debug

```
https://www.google.com/maps/place/45%C2%B047'59.2%22N+15%C2%B058'13.1%22E/@45.7997778,15.9681169,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d45.799793!4d15.970302
```

Code

```
$location = "45.799793,15.970302"; 
$zoom_lvl = "10z";

<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/@<?php echo $location; ?>,<?php echo $zoom_lvl; ?>">Go to Google Map</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This url format should work ok:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?&z=10&q=45.799793+15.970302&ll=45.799793+15.970302
```